# ksh variable declaration and loop

Tags: ksh, variable

I need to work and understand a ksh script. The variable declaration is done in a different way I am used to:

```
STA=${1:-blabla}
```

I don't really understand what does the "1:-" stands for?
Is it possible to make a loop with this variable declaration such as:

```
STA=${1:-blabla blabla2 blabla3}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`${var:-x}` means "if var is unset or empty, replace it with x". As such it depends on what you mean by "mak[ing] a loop".

If you make a loop by splitting on `$IFS`, then yes, you can use this to create a variable for a loop. However, if that's what you want to do, I'd recommend using a ksh array instead:

```
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
  set -A sta blabla blabla2 blabla3 # ksh88/pdksh/mksh/ksh93
  sta=(blabla blabla2 blabla3)      # ksh93/mksh
else
  sta=("$@") # use the positional parameters if provided
fi

for x in "${sta[@]}"; do [...]
```

Answer (score 1):

`${1}` is the first argument to the script.  The substitution modifier `:-` is explained in the [manual page for `ksh`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ksh):

> ${*name*:-*word*}
>
> If *name* is set and not NULL, it is substituted; otherwise, *word* is substituted.

Thus, if an argument is provided to your script or function, `$STA` will be assigned the value of that argument.  If there is no `${1}`, then `$STA` will be assigned the default value "blabla" instead.

This is not a loop operator; if you want to loop over several values you'd need syntax other than `${1:-blabla blabla2 blabla3}`.